# SharePoint page not loading in personal tab of static app (MS Teams desktop client)

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

When adding a **SharePoint page as a static tab in my custom personal app**, the added SharePoint page is not loaded in the MS Teams **desktop** client, but works as expected in the **web** client.

*Also*, when switching to Developer Preview the tab starts to work. Even when switching *out of* Developer Preview the web page *still* loads as expected.

#### Steps to Reproduce

- Create a page in SharePoint online
- Create a new MS Teams app (e.g. in App Studio's Manifest editor)
- Add a new **Personal** tab, linking to the SharePoint page
- Install the MS Teams app (e.g. with App Studio's Test and Distribute)
- Open the MS Teams app
  --> The SharePoint page is not loaded (nothing is shown, just a blank screen)
- Switch to developer preview (& sign in if needed)
- Open the MS Teams app
  --> The SharePoint page is loaded correctly
- Switch **out of** developer preview (& sign in if needed)
- Open the MS Teams app
  --> The SharePoint page is **still** loaded correctly

PS: it seems initially there is a redirect happening to /_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx, which redirects to the MS login page. However, this redirect is not happening when the switch to or from developer preview has occured. So, it looks like initially MS Teams does not pass authenticated correctly?

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try adding following in your App Manifest as workaround and let us know if you are facing any issue?

```
"staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "TestTabId",
      "name": "Test Tab",
      "contentUrl": "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/MyTestSite/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=/teams/MyTestSite/SitePages/Test.aspx",
      "scopes": ["personal"],
      "websiteUrl": "https://fullwebsite.website.com/about"
    }
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "*.login.microsoftonline.com",
    "microsoft.sharepoint.com",
    "microsoft.sharepoint-df.com",
    "spoppe-a.akamaihd.net",
    "spoprod-a.akamaihd.net",
    "resourceseng.blob.core.windows.net",
    "msft.spoppe.com"
  ],
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "resource": "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com",
    "id": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000"
  }
```

Comment: Hi Wajeed, this indeed solved my issue. Found out about this last Friday as well. I had logged this with MS support, but apparently they were not aware of this... Hope you guys add it to their support info as well. :)