# How can I pin a Sharepoint's WebPart app?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have developed a Sharepoint's WebPart. This app works fine and now I need something similar to integrate with Teams.

I have been researching about the best way to develop the app for Teams. As far as I know, there are two ways of doing this: 
 1. I can develop a new app only for Teams 
 2. I can "reuse" the Sharepoint's Webpart.

According to the second one option, I have made some little changes and now the app based in the WebPart is working in Teams.

My doubt is the next one. The application is a "Tab" associated to a channel and the client wants that the app icon appears in the menu of the left side.

When I try to add the icon in: https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/app-setup, this new application based on the WebPart, never appears and I don't know the way to add the icon in the menu.

Could somebody help me?

Kind regards

Comment: You can pin only Personal Apps to the left rail. Could you load your [SharePoint page as personal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593508/sharepoint-page-not-loading-in-personal-tab-of-static-app-ms-teams-desktop-clie/57770834#57770834) (static) tab in your App and then try to pin it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pin only Personal Apps to the left rail. Please add your [SharePoint page as personal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57593508/sharepoint-page-not-loading-in-personal-tab-of-static-app-ms-teams-desktop-clie/57770834#57770834) (static) tab in your App and then pin it.